# Deleting from base with ContextMenu

Tags: android

So i am preety new with this SQLite i finaly managed to create base and work with it etc. Now i created ContextMenu thath you will be able to delete item from listView  on which context menu was opened. Here is my current code.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Ann extends ListActivity{
    private CommentsDataSource datasource;
    EditText edit;
    ListView bump;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ann);

        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();      

        List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Comment>) getListAdapter();
        Comment comment = null;
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:  
            edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxt);            
            Editable txt=(Editable)edit.getText();
            String vnos = txt.toString();           
            comment = datasource.createComment(vnos);
            adapter.add(comment);
            edit.setText("");
            break;  
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        datasource.open();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        datasource.close();
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

Now i know thath i need to make method for `public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

but how to manage now to delete item which was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I ask why you don't use a SimpleCursorAdapter to create the list?  It looks like you're getting a cursor and turning into an array... why take that extra step?  It's useful in that if you make an addition/deletion to the database, you can simply use the `requery()` method to regenerate/update the list.

Anyway, should you decide to go with a SimpleCursorAdapter, `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` would be the way to go.  An example from one of my projects:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    if (item.getTitle() == "Delete Member") {
        mDbHelper.deleteMember(info.id);
  mMemberCursor.requery();
  return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Note that I created my menu view programatically, so you may need to change the `if` statement to something that will work better for your set-up with an inflated menu resource.

`info.id` is the row id from the database that represents the line of the list you clicked.
`mDbHelper.deleteMember()` is a method from my database helper for deleting records.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The context menu is not listItem specific, ie. id does not know which item was clicked.

Go for an onItemClicked or onItemLongClick version.

To do the latter implement the onItemLongClick interface on you activity

`public class Ann extends ListActivity implements OnItemLongClickListener`

and add the onItemLongClick method

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // do something with your datasource and the position
    return false;
}
```